# Output inner dictionary KeyValuePair to Console

Tags: c#

Struggling with this code, very new to c# and I've tried multiple answers on stackoverflow before writing this question so please hear me out...

```
var onlinePlayers = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string,string>>();
var count = 0;
foreach (BasePlayer player in BasePlayer.activePlayerList)
{
    onlinePlayers.Add(
        count, 
        new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "SteamID",  player.userID.ToString() },
            { "PlayerName", player.displayName.ToString() },
            { "IPAddress", Regex.Replace(player.net.connection.ipaddress, @":{1}[0-9]{1}\d*", "").ToString }
        }
    );

    count += 1;
}

foreach (var k in onlinePlayers.Keys)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in onlinePlayers[k])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see

```
SteamID: 1231231221321
PlayerName: HelloWorld
IPAddress: 127.0.0.1
```

for each item in the collection.

Compiler error:

> Error while compiling StatLogger.cs(38,111): error CS1503: Argument #2 cannot
>   convert method group expression to type string

Comment: Try `foreahc(var k in onlonePlayers.Keys) Consoe.WriteLine("{0} :{1}", k, onlineplayers[k]);`

Comment: That gives: Error while compiling StatLogger.cs(38,111): error CS1503: Argument `#2` cannot
convert `method group` expression to type `string`

Comment: My mistake, it's a Dictionary... should be nested loops - the first to get the inner dictionary and the second to get the values for it. Not on a computer right now, too hard to write this on my cellphone....

Comment: I tried `foreach (var innerDict in onlinePlayers.Values) { foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in innerDict) { Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value); } }` to the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses `()` at the end of your `.ToString()`.

> { "IPAddress", Regex.Replace(player.net.connection.ipaddress,
>   @":{1}[0-9]{1}\d*", "").ToString }

Update :

Also `player.net.connection.ipaddress.ToString()`

The above will turn the IP into a string and that should prevent the error.

Comment: You were right, it's `player.net.connection.ipaddress` causing that error

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to enumerate the `Dictionary`'s key, rather than the `Dictionary` itself.

Try this:

```
foreach (player in onlinePlayers) {
  foreach (playerInfo in player.Value) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", playerInfo.Key, playerInfo.Value);
  }
}
```

See if that helps.